# Predict egg drop outcome in random container

Tags: materials, design, structural-analysis, control-theory

What elements affect the outcome of a raw egg drop in a random container?

I’ve considered air resistance, mass, size of container, size and type of padding. Are there other elements?

Comment: Whether the egg breaks.

Comment: Friction of what against what?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Objects falling through air create friction or drag. See: https://study.com/academy/answer/objects-falling-through-air-experience-a-type-of-friction-called.html

Comment: Friction and drag are not typically analogous - friction being related to a coefficient which is independent of geometry, and a reaction force, where drag is related to a coefficient which depends on geometry, and the square of the velocity through the air.

Comment: As such, even though drag is a "type of friction", it's not clear what you mean if you simply state that you have considered friction without specifying between what.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift So it is friction....?

Answer (score 3):

Whether the egg breaks is a function of how much pressure is put on the egg. The same as if you had an egg on the table and started to push down on it with your hand - eventually the force will be high enough to cause the shell to break. If you used a pin instead of your hand then the force required would be lower as its spread over a smaller area.

So, assuming you can find through experimentation an expression for how much force it takes to break an egg for a given surface area (likely not constant due to the curvature of the shell), then all you need to work out is the peak force of impact, and the area of application.

Area is influenced by the type of padding.

Force is tricker - we need to look at the deceleration of the egg from its final speed before impact.

The final speed will be affected by the mass, and any air resistance (is there a parachute?)

The peak deceleration will depend on the design of any crumple zones. Does the container bounce or just come to a standstill on the ground? A longer total deceleration phase will mean a lower peak force and a safer egg.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exhaustive list.. but:

1. The air resistance and mass of the container+egg will change the impact velocity.
2. Deceleration distance. The container and ground will give slightly on impact. This will create a (short) distance over which the deceleration takes place. This is what crumple zones do. If you decelerate over 10mm instead of 1mm you reduce the g forces by a factor of 10. This is also why things break more when dropped on concrete, it doesn't give much on impact.
3. Force on the egg. If the container places uneven force on the shell of the egg, then the egg will tend to crack where the force varies. For example if the point of the egg pushes against a flat surface in the direction of the impact, it will break where the point meets the surface. A surface exactly the shape of the egg is ideal.
4. Container deformation. Even if the container is exactly the shape of the egg internally, the container itself may deform on impact, therefor pushing on the egg unevenly and potentially breaking it. Ideally the portion of the container surrounding the egg should be completely stiff and non-deformable.

Following from 3 and 4. If the egg container is perfectly rigid, and perfectly fits the egg, then it will be essentially unbreakable no matter the drop height. This is impossible, but more rigid and more fitting is better.